# C++ Memory allocation with class and string

Tags: c++, class, memory

I didn't know why this code run perfectly..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class Person
{
    public:
     char m_Name[1];
};

int main()
{
    const char* name = "Kim Na In";
    Person* pPerson = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person) + strlen(name)); 
    pPerson->m_Name[0] = '\0';
    strcat(pPerson->m_Name, name);
    std::cout << pPerson->m_Name << std::endl;
}
```

In my code, I can't understand how can "std::cout << pPerson->m_Name << std::endl;" this code print the string "Kim Na In".

Even The Person is a class and the pPerson is the successive Person class... It is not array or char * ..! How is it possible?

Comment: Using `malloc` here is wrong. The memory for the object is allocated but the constructor is not called. In c++ use only `new` if you must allocate manually, or better - avoid manual allocations as much as possible. In this case it is not clear why you need to allocate dynamic memory at all.

Comment: Also the memory required for `Person` object is `sizeof(Person)` (**without** `+ strlen(name)`).

Comment: Another issue is that the destination in your `strcat` call (`pPerson->m_Name`) is not big enough to accomodate the string `name`.

Comment: The bottom line is that your code contains UB (**Undefined Behavior**) and therefore anything can happen, including the appearance of "working" code.

Comment: @wohlstad That's probably why the user is trying to overallocate the memory size to begin with. But yikes, if this isn't the most UB code ever i don't know what is. Everything about this is so wrong

Comment: Looks like _UB_ all over. Use `std::string` in c++ code, period.

Comment: @wohlstad The type is implicit-lifetime, so `malloc` without `new` is ok in this specific case.

Comment: @user17732522 I guess you are correct. Nevertheless I think it is a bad practice. Wouldn't you agree ?

Comment: ```sizeof(Person)``` is ```1 byte``` and you allocated ```1 + strlen(name)``` bytes in memory. With ```pPerson->m_Name[0] = '\0';``` you copied a null character to first byte of the allocated memory and with ```strcat(pPerson->m_Name, name);``` you overwrite it and because your memory is large enough, did not crash. Your code has many design problems. Basically it is not ```C++``` design at all.

Comment: I find that code in quite credible post .... so I think there is something special that I didn't know...But, Now I understand that code is something wrong! Thank you your advises!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `strcat(pPerson->m_Name, name);` has undefined behavior because `m_Name` is too short to store `name`. It only has length `1`.

Undefined behavior means that you have no guarantee provided by the standard on how the program will behave. That it seems to be working is a valid outcome of that, but so is it failing in arbitrary ways or producing unexpected output.

Practically speaking, you are allocating more memory behind the `Person` object with `malloc` and compilers usually do not do any optimization based on object structure such as where the `Person` object or its `m_Name` member actually ends. So if the compiler translates this naively, there simply is enough space after `m_Name` to store the additional characters. So it will just work as if all the extra space belonged to the array at the end of the `Person` object.

In fact, in standard C, but not standard C++, there is a similar construct that is *defined* to work the way you are using it, called *flexible array member*. The only difference is that this *requires* the size of the array member to be declared with without a size (    `char m_Name[];`). Compilers often support this as an extension in C++ as well to some degree. Before this was standardized in C99, some compilers also supported it as an extension to C with zero size instead (`char m_Name[0];`).